# How to make disqus authorize api call?

Tags: disqus

I am trying to authorize api call by https://disqus.com/api/oauth/2.0/authorize/?client_id=XXXXX

I am getting following response in call back url

```
state=&error_description=You+may+reference+this+error+as+Unknown+error&error=server_error
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Where and how are you trying to authorize this? If this is a coding question please provide the code used.

Comment: @harmonica141 I am just trying this url request with my public key and domain.
https://disqus.com/api/oauth/2.0/authorize/?client_id=xxxxx&scope=read,write&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://wwww.mysite.com/

Comment: What are you trying to do this from?

Comment: @harmonica141 I am trying to get data from disqus with their api call. I need to get access token before accessing them. We will get a code from this request and then we can get access token by passing code retrieved from first call.

Comment: But what REST client are you using? Where do you post the request from? Insomnia?

Comment: @harmonica141 I am trying with postman chrome extension. Can you please tell me what is issue and how to get access token for disqus?

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from the official [disqus documentation](https://disqus.com/api/docs/auth/) you will need to acquire a fresh OAuth token by posting

```
POST https://disqus.com/api/oauth/2.0/access_token/?
    grant_type=refresh_token&
    client_id=PUBLIC_KEY&
    client_secret=SECRET_KEY&
    refresh_token=REFRESH_TOKEN
```

Comment: How can we get REFRESH_TOKEN?

Comment: Actually, I want to display all comments on my website by disqus api. We can display it by simply providing api public key. But, what i am trying to do is we give moderate permissions to some users. So, when they login, they should be able to approve comments. 

But, Admin user only has api keys on disqus. Is it possible to add other users also can have API access??

Comment: This changes your question. You should edit accordingly. I'm out from here. I can do REST but I am not into disqus, sorry.